# log files location on apache

Tags: apache, apache2

I found in my httpd configuration this line:

```
    CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

But how can I navigate to that folder, when I use this:

```
cd /logs/access_log
```

I get:

```
-bash: cd: /logs/access_log: No such file or directory
```

I wanted to zip log file and move it to `var/www/html/` folder, so I can download it.

Im new to all this after windows, the OS is CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

The folder is relative to your Apache folder.

Let's say your apache folder is `/usr/local/apache2`.

Then `logs/access_log` is pointed to `/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log`.

If you want the logs folder to be in root (which I don't recommend) your setting should be.

```
CustomLog /logs/access_log common
```

Comment: should be ? It's already is `CustomLog logs/access_log common` by default. I dont understand. or do you mean that extra forward slash before `logs`? How can I download log files? whats the easiest way WITHOUT cpanel?

Comment: Exactly, the first slash means a lot when we're talking about directories, :)

Comment: ok, then how do we navigate to my current log folder? is it possible to zip a log file and move it to my www folder so I can download it?

Comment: Like I said, it's under your apache folder, that varies depending on the linux distribution or if you installed apache from source. What linux distribution are you using ?

Comment: On CentOS the logs are based on the ServerRoot configured, which by default is /etc/httpd, so your log would be at /etc/httpd/logs/access_log. You'll notice there is a symbolic link to /var/log/httpd, there is where the log files are actually.